# Sealing Dishwasher Door

Tags: dishwasher

The rubber gasket sealing my dishwasher has a gap through which water sometimes escapes. I tried sealing it using caulk but most of it washed away. Is there another sealant I can use? I'm considering J-B Weld, but the label on it says it's unsafe to ingest. Is there a risk of it washing onto the dishes and making us sick? When I applied the caulk, it had been sitting in our cold garage. Do I need to warm up the caulk before applying it? Is it safe to use in the dishwasher, too?

Answer (score 1):

#### Replacement of the gasket is the best solution

The catch is that (a) replacement gaskets tend to be relatively expensive and (b) gaskets can be tough to replace. Take a look at [Appliance Parts Pros](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/) or a similar site and search for your dishwasher model # to see if a replacement gasket is readily available.

Answer (score 0):

A new gasket as per the other answer is by far the best solution.

However, I have had, albeit temporary, success with making a filler from silicone or bathroom joint sealer - you want one that is just slightly soft when it is cured.

I made a "dam" with masking tape and filled to match the height. Allow to cure thoroughly and make sure the surface is very clean and dry before starting.